# Sending Email at particular date in Android

Tags: java, android

I want to send an email at particular date when my app is install but not open on the phone.How to do this. Can someone help me.Thanks to appreciate.

Comment: write a service and broadcast receviers for the same

Comment: service that what u need

Comment: This appears to be your assignment from college. Try to implement something on your own by reading few links,face failures,and then come here with a proper specific question.

Answer (score 1):

Android Services allow you to run code even if your application is not currently in the foreground.

Start here reading here about Android Services:

- http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: Can you give me sample code.

Comment: Sample code for what precisely? Sending emails? Implementing a service? Please read the linked documentation. If something is not clear you'll want to ask again.

Comment: I have tried but it's not run and getting error of runTimeException .

Comment: Post a new question your question together with your code and the exception stack trace. Then link the new question as a follow up here.